# Get Text Content of xml element

Tags: java, xml, jdom

So, i have some question about xml Documents in Java. Can i get all text(only text) content of some element and all descendant's elements of this element, without to iterate through all this elements and using Element.getText()? By another words, it must be some analogous function to JavaScript textContent. Or i must to iterate through all nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate and append.